# Live Wallpaper preferences problem

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, live-wallpaper

So I have this big stupid problem with the preferences in my live-wallpaper.

First, `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences`, doesn't work. I'm calling it in my Main class, a subclass of WallpaperService in the function onCreate. For the parameter, I first tried "this" and then `this.getBaseContext()`, but it doesn't matter. So, when I print the values, nothing shows up!

Second, I saw in another answer here that to put some default values, use something like `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this.getBaseContext(), R.xml.setting, true);`. So, this, doesn't get my defaultValues at all. They're all zeros and even one values from my `setting.xml` doesn't show up in the list. I explicitly put a `android:defaultValue` for each of them.

Note that once I put values for each of them in the preferences, this problem doesn't happen. But still, for someone who installs my app, it needs to work on the first time it's launched.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences are a bear.  I always start with a working example, and then modify it to suit my needs; it's impossible to remember the formalisms :-).  The "obvious" place to start is the "second" Cube example in the SDK, which uses a preferences activity to choose between cube and dodecahedron shapes.  For something more sophisticated, you might wanna look at Moonblink's "Substrate" package, which combines multiple wallpapers, and  has complex settings.  Project home is here: http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Substrate , then click Source at top left, then Browse, Trunk, Substrate, src, etc.  GF